# javascript Larger image viewer

Tags: javascript, html

i have a set of small sized images on the browser. What i want to do is when i click on the image a larger format of the image clicked will show up in a div above. here is javascript code. The code below shows an empty image. how do i fix this? I dont want jquery to do this.

```
//for images
var largeImageViewer = document.getElementById('large-image-viewer');
var smallImages = document.querySelectorAll('.small-images');

for(i = 0; i < smallImages.length; i++){
smallImages[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if (event) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.style.width = 500 + "px";
    img.style.height = 500 + "px";
    img.src = smallImages.src;
    largeImageViewer.appendChild(img);
    };
});
}
```

Comment: why did someone give my question a negative rating? i dont get it. im just trying to get help on my question. instead of doing that why dont u tell me what i did wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Inside an event handler the current element can be get by 'this' keyword.

```
img.src = this.src;
```